# Ошибка авторизации через ActiveDirectory с Apache + Kerberos при HTTP запросе от клиента

Tags: php, клиент-сервер, kerberos

сложно составить вопрос, поэтому предложения правок и подсказки приветствуются.

О проблеме:

1. Имеется веб приложение: frontend js, backend php, веб-сервер Apache.
2. Frontend и Backend имеют разные директории на сервере.
3. Весь Frontend настроен на url `/`, и корневая директория `/var/www/frontend/dist/public`.
4. Backend настроен на 3 пути:

4.1. Простая авторизация - url `/api/auth/`, и корневая директория `/var/www/backend/public/auth/`.

4.2. Active Directory авторизация - url `/api/ad/`, и корневая директория `/var/www/backend/public/ad/`.

4.3. Операции и действия - url `/api/graphql/`, и корневая директория `/var/www/backend/public/graphql/`.

5. В Apache настроен Kerberos на путь `/var/www/backend/public/ad/`, который должен взаимодействовать с браузером. В итоге на PHP должно быть значение `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.

```bash
<Directory /var/www/backend/public/ad>
  <RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
      Require all granted
      Require not ip 192.168.1.0/24
    </RequireAll>
    AuthType GSSAPI
    AuthName "Project"
    GssapiCredStore keytab:/etc/httpd/projecthttp.keytab
    GssapiSSLonly On
    GssapiBasicAuth Off
    Require valid-user
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

6. Всё работает, если я открою тестовый файл PHP `example.com/api/ad/test.php`, в котором отображается значение `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. Никаких окон не всплывает. Всё работает как должно работать.
7. Но, когда открывается страница frontend, там делается клиентский HTTP запрос к `example.com/api/ad/`. Заканчивается тем, что всплывает окно "авторизации Windows" в домене. То есть данные не передаются автоматически, как это было в пункте 6. Авторизация не выполняется и запрашиваются данные. При их вводе, окно не исчезает, данные запрашиваются бесконечно. Если закрыть всплывающее окно, то результат HTTP запроса к `example.com/api/ad/` будет `401 нет авторизации`.

Как я понял, проблема в том, что если в браузере первое действие - это скрипт сервера, всё работает.
Если это действие вторичное, то есть мы перешли на страницу index.html интерфейса, а там приложение делает запрос, то не работает.

Как решить эту проблему?
Что я не правильно делаю или не так понял?

Моя задача, это в интерфейсе отображать кнопку входа через "Active Directory", если присутствует значение `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. Интерфейс на странице входа делает этот запрос.